# Twitter API 2.0 - Unable to fetch user.fields

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

I am using API version 2.0 and unable to fetch the `user.fields` results. All other parameters seem to be returning results correctly. I'm following [this documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/fields).

```py
url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all"

query_params = {
    "query": "APPL",
    "max_results": "10",
    "tweet.fields": "created_at,lang,text,author_id",
    "user.fields": "name,username,created_at,location",
    "expansions": "referenced_tweets.id.author_id",
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=query_params).json()
```

Sample result:

```
{
  'author_id': '1251347502013521925',
  'text': 'All conspiracy. But watch for bad news on Apple.  Such a vulnerable stocktechnically for the biggest market cap @ $2.1T ( Thanks Jay). This is the glue for the bulls. But, they stopped innovating when Steve died, built a fancy office and split the stock. $appl',
  'lang': 'en',
  'created_at': '2021-06-05T02:33:48.000Z',
  'id': '1401004298738311168',
  'referenced_tweets': [{
    'type': 'retweeted',
    'id': '1401004298738311168'
  }]
}
```

As you can see, the following information is not returned: `name`, `username`, and `location`.

Any idea how to retrieve this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does actually return the correct data. I tested this myself.

A full example response will be structured like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_at": "2021-06-05T02:33:48.000Z",
      "lang": "en",
      "id": "1401004298738311168",
      "text": "All conspiracy. But watch for bad news on Apple.  Such a vulnerable stocktechnically for the biggest market cap @ $2.1T ( Thanks Jay). This is the glue for the bulls. But, they stopped innovating when Steve died, built a fancy office and split the stock. $appl",
      "author_id": "1251347502013521925",
      "referenced_tweets": [
        {
          "type": "retweeted",
          "id": "1401004298738311168"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Gary Casper",
        "id": "1251347502013521925",
        "username": "Hisel1979",
        "created_at": "2020-07-11T13:39:58.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The sample result you provided comes from within the `data` object. However, the expanded object data will be nested in the `includes` object (in your case `name`, `username`, and `location`). The corresponding `user` object can be referenced via the `author_id` field.

Comment: I got it now, thank you. I was just scraping out the data in my code :) . Dint know about the includes.